# Java-like language with unsigned and POD types

Tags: java

After I mastered Java I can say for sure that I like it much more than C++ which I used for more then 10 years. The things that really annoy me is that Java lacks of operator overloading, `unsigned` byte and `struct` data types. That why you have to use different hacks to do low level network, video and audio data processing.

I wonder is there any Java-like language (and VM) with `unsigned` byte and `struct`-like data types? Also why not to extend the Java standard adding these features?

Comment: C# has structs, unsigned types and runs theoretically on linux (mono).

Comment: That 'theoretically' is an understatement. The bottom line is that C# lacks the community support of the JVM world and thus Mono is still a very immature project.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Scala. It's a different paradigm than C++ since it mixes OOP and functional programming but it has many features you might like in the familiar JVM runtime environment. You will get mixins, case classes, operator overloading and a lot of features that will easily let you implement low level features using high level abstractions without losing performance. For example in Odersky's Programming in Scala there is a great example of how to build a data structure to store 2-bit long fields efficiently but with a nice functional/OOP interface on top of it. This will easily make up for the fact that bytes are still signed.